# how to avoid sending multiple request in backbone js. cache is not able clear

Tags: backbone.js

ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); to clear application cache. but when i observer network tab in chrome multiple request are firing.

[image: request trace]

Attached image shows network tab and how the duplicate requests are firing.

Please suggest me how to avoid duplicate request.

Answer (score 0):

By default, backbone uses jQuery.ajax, which means that ajaxSetup({ cache: false }) is from juery.

Below is straight from [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Setting cache to false means that it will send out request each time with unique URL (see the timestamp at the end) and therefore not to cache.

===================

cache (default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp')
Type: Boolean
If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser. Note: Setting cache to false will only work correctly with HEAD and GET requests. It works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters. The parameter is not needed for other types of requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL that has already been requested by a GET.

===================